# Делимся ранее неопубликованными / не опубликованными статьями

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

> А в этом посте делимся ранее неопубликованными статьями нашей ученицы Серафимы.

"Неопубликованными" правильно написано или нет?

У автора написано так, я бы раздельно написала, то есть "не опубликованными".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*А в этом посте делимся **ранее не опубликованными** статьями нашей ученицы Серафимы.*

Здесь раздельное написание причастия и частицы НЕ при наличии зависимого слова (***ранее***).

Пример:

*Эта книга, куда вошли **ранее не переводившиеся рассказы**, как ранние, так и написанные зрелым мастером, хороший подарок всем поклонникам творчества замечательного немецкого писателя.* [Юлия Рахаева.  2002.11.04]